# How to convert an integer with or without a negative symbol to a timezone offset for CONVERT_TZ?

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

So in a database table, we store a place's timezone offset as an integer with or without a negative sign (- or dash) in front of it, in a varchar(3) column, like so:

`-5` (the tics are not part of the value obviously)

This needs to be used in CONVERT_TZ function in the from_tz param... which only works with a string timezone or an offset of format like `-05:00`, which I'm not seeing how to do yet.

```
function definition: CONVERT_TZ(dt, from_tz, to_tz)
```

It's not feasible for me to build something in another language to convert -5 to a string timezone than pass it to from_tz because it has to be in the SQL because of the fetch and comparison, and we don't have time to fix the data values and the table and its implementation across servers.

I've tried REGEX, SIGN, SUBSTRING in various combinations... but they so far do not provide a consistent solution to a timezone being 0 or -3 or 5 (and coercion doesn't appear to work), and when CONVERT_TZ can't compare, it returns NULL, breaking anything that relies on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for SQL string hackery.

```
SET @v := +4;
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), 
                  CONCAT( IF(@v < 0 , '-', '+'),
                          RIGHT(CONCAT('00', CAST(ABS(@v) AS char(2)), ':00'), 5)),
                  'America/Halifax')
```

That `CONCAT()` expression makes any integer n into `0n:00` then prepends either `+` or `-`.  It's not pretty but it works.